# Multitenancy - design pattern

Tags: javascript, mysql, multi-tenant, auth0

I have a requirement to design the following:

- There will be one main domain
- There is only on application that runs and servers all
- Multitenancy, with different databases. User per database (special users share many databases)
- Using Auth0

User logs in, system recognizes where does he belong and the application uses appropriate database.

I have made a prototype that relies on subdomain name, and in theory that should have worked. In my prototype, system relies on HOST. Now the requirements changed, and I cant use the subdomain as a asset to differentiate.

I cant even begin to think how to organize all of this, in my mind Redis rings the bell. But I dont know :(

I would appreciate any pointers, if someone has done something like this already?

I am using React / Hapi.js / Sequalize (MySQL) / Auth0

Comment: you have the login particulars that help you figure out the tenant context which should be replaced instead of the domain based resolution. For example, having a unique email within the application will cause `john.smith@tenant1.com` to belong to `tenant1` which can be used to set the context as `tenant1`. HTH

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so already you should check: [Using Auth0 with Multi-tenant Apps](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/using-auth0-with-multi-tenant-apps)

It has a few different examples and also provides guidelines on how to model this type of architectures in Auth0.